# Append React child component to native HTML element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, appendchild, react-dom

I'm using a Google Maps overlay and trying to append my React Component inside, using **this.container.appendChild**.

The current error I'm getting is:

**MapMarker.js:14 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'**

Here is my (relevant) code.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import _ from 'lodash';
import MapMarkerComponent from './MapMarkerComponent';

class MapMarker extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.container = document.createElement('DIV');
    this.container.setAttribute('class', 'map--pin');
    this.container.appendChild(MapMarkerComponent);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    if (window.google) {
      this.markerOverlay = new window.google.maps.OverlayView();
      this.markerOverlay.onAdd = _.bind(this.onAdd, this);
      this.markerOverlay.draw = _.bind(this.draw, this);
      this.markerOverlay.onRemove = _.bind(this.onRemove, this);
      this.markerOverlay.setMap(this.props.map);
    }
  }

  onAdd() {
    this.pane = this.markerOverlay.getPanes().overlayLayer;
    this.pane.appendChild(this.container);
    ....
  }

  ... draw() and onRemove() methods

  render() {
    return <div>ReactDOM.render( this.panes );</div>;
  }
}

export default MapMarker;
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What is `this.panes`? Did you mean `this.pane`?

Comment: This looks invalid `this.container.appendChild(MapMarkerComponent);` You are trying to add a React component as if it where a html element.

Comment: Thanks @DarrenSweeney for the pickup.

Comment: @Kunukn - yes, that's the problem - do you know how do I append it as a React Component to a HTML element?

Comment: Yes. `ReactDOM.render(<MapMarkerComponent/>, this.container)` This results in this.container html element containing the html element version of MapMarkerComponent.

Comment: You cannot do this `return <div>ReactDOM.render( this.panes );</div>;` this.panes (or `this.pane`) is a dynamically created html element. You have to add it in the classical JS way. e.g. `document.appendChild(this.pane)`. I would reconsider your approach. You are mixing React with html elements a bit too much than you might need.

Comment: That works, thanks @Kunukn - I greatly appreciate your help. I'm also able to pass props to my component, using `<MapMarkerComponent/>` which is perfect.

Comment: If you have better suggestions of how to do this, I'd greatly appreciate any advice. Ideally I'd like to just render out the components and have them nested instead of using the ReactDOM.render()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160015/discussion-between-desmond-and-kunukn).